# pop-up as value is entered in text box using jquery

Tags: jquery

When the value is entered, I want an alert, its a copy/paste text box, using jquery

```
('#test).bind('onblur',function(){
  var h = ('#test).attr('value');
alert(h);
});


<input type=text id=test>
```

Thanks
Jean

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
<input type="text" id="test" />
```

**JQuery**

```
$(function(){
    $('#test').blur(function(){
      alert($(this).val());
    });
});
```

Comment: .value is not going to be a property on a jQuery object. There is no need to encase 'this' inside a jQuery construct.

Comment: @Tejs: fixed it before even your comment :)

Comment: @Jean: Have you included the jquery library in your page before that code?

Comment: @sarfraz, yes, this is just an addition I am doing, there is no js error, the alert box just does not bling!

Comment: @Jean: did you try `focusout` instead of `blur`? and is the textbox created on-the-fly?

Comment: @sarfraz did focusout, just does not move, also the blur, now I wonder why, it works perfectly with .bind('click')

Answer (score 1):

- missing quote behind your selector
- typo in `function()`
- replace `onblur` with `blur` or `focusout`
- use `var h = $(this).val();`

blur and focusout only fire wenn that element loses the focus.

Answer (score 1):

Not quite sure what you want, but is it something like this?

```
$("#test").change(function() { alert($(this).val()); });
```

The alert shows the text entered in the box when it is changed.

Comment: I guessed change might be more appropriate than blur. But it's easily substituted for another event - http://api.jquery.com/category/events/

Answer (score -1):

Not knowing your full HTML source, I would imagine:

```
$('#test').blur(function()
{
   alert(this.value);
});
```

should do the trick. The code you have entered doesn't seem to be valid JavaScript, and it looks like you might be trying to complicate the event attaching and handler with too much code.

Comment: @Tejs: You should replace `this.value` with `$(this).val()`

Answer (score -1):

```
('#test input').bind('blur',function(){
  var h = ('#test).attr('value');
alert(h);
});
```

adding an input in the selector should work for the blur

Comment: if this is the answer, then you can mark it as the answer.  it doesn't need to be upvoted